# How create nested child node in firebase realtime database android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I'm trying make nested child node but I have no idea how

this is my data

[image]

I want make like fake bank

like under phone i want add another data called like donate  and inside it I want add node called history like any time donor donate money it should store in the history
anyone know how i can do that ???

this is my codes

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_donor__registration);
    doname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editname);
    dopass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editpass);
    docon=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editcon);
    dophone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editphone);
    doemail=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editemail);
    btn_register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    myref1= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Donors");
    firebaseAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();//d


    btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String do_name=doname.getText().toString();
            String do_pass=dopass.getText().toString();
            String do_con=docon.getText().toString();
            String do_phone=dophone.getText().toString();
            String do_email=doemail.getText().toString();

            //validation

            if(do_name.equals(""))
                doname.setError("User name Should not be empty");
            else if(do_pass.equals(""))
                dopass.setError("Password Should not be empty");
            else if(do_con.equals(""))
                docon.setError("Confirm Password Should not be empty");
            else if(do_phone.equals(""))
                dophone.setError("Phone Should not be empty");
            else if(do_email.equals(""))
                doemail.setError("Email Should not be empty");
            else if(!do_pass.equals(do_con))
                docon.setError("Password and Confirm password should match");
            else if(do_pass.length()<8)
                dopass.setError("Password Should be at least 8 charaters");
            else if(do_phone.length()<8)
                dophone.setError("Phone number should be  8 digits");
            else if(!do_phone.startsWith("7")&& !do_phone.startsWith("9"))
                dophone.setError("Should Start with 7 or 9");
              else if(!do_email.matches(emailpattern))
                doemail.setError("Email Should be correct");



                //else

            else {


                //


                myref1.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        int flag = 0;
                        for (DataSnapshot d : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Donors ado = d.getValue(Donors.class);
                            if (ado.d_email.equalsIgnoreCase(do_email)) {
                                flag = 1;
                                Toast.makeText(Donor_Registration.this, "Donor already exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }



                        if (flag == 0) {

                            //
                            firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(doemail.getText().toString(),dopass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(Donor_Registration.this,"Donor registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                                    }

                                  //  else
                                   // {
                                       // Toast.makeText(Donor_Registration.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                  //  }

                                }
                            });


                           Donors ado = new Donors(do_name, do_pass, do_phone, do_email);
                           String id = myref1.push().getKey();
                           myref1.child(id).setValue(ado);
                          Toast.makeText(Donor_Registration.this, "Donor registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();







                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

            }

        }



    });














}
```

Comment: you can directly use the child node

Comment: yes but Donor will donate many times I want something help me ...like i want every time this donor will donate it must store it in the history

Comment: like i have (donor) in side i should have (donor info) inside it his information and i want (history) inside it  every time this donor will donate it must store it there

Comment: You want to add data in `d_phone` right ?

Comment: no i want add something called donation or history

Comment: every time donor donate money it will save in the date in the history node of course there will be many donors every donor he will see his history only

Answer (score 0):

Your code is setting the entire donor node.

```
FirebaseReference donorsNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Donors");
FirebaseReference donorNode = donorsNode.child(donorId);
donorNode.setValue(entireDonorValue);
```

To update it with a donation just set a child node inside the existing donor node.

```
FirebaseReference donorsNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Donors");
FirebaseReference donorNode = donorsNode.child(donorId);
FirebaseReference donationsNode = donorNode.child("Donations");
FirebaseReference donationNode = donationsNode.child(donationId);
donationNode.setValue(donationValue);
```